# Connection to neo4j incorrect in android studio

Tags: java, android, neo4j

Hi I would like to use neo4j in an app made in android studio on mac using neo4j version 5.6.0 desktop on mac, but when I try to connect with "bolt://192.168.X.X:7687" it gives me error it's from as message on neo4j: "ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the Neo4j certificate is configured to use. WebSocket readyState` is: 3".

I tried uncommenting these dbms.connectors .default_listen_address=0.0.0.0 and server.bolt.listen_address

but it didn't work and it's not a question of the port because if I activate the server with "bolt://192.168.X.X:7687" the server c onnette but from client app I have: ""W/System.err: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it ."

As a client I made the connection in android studio with AsyncTask like this:

```
`  try {
                String uri = "bolt://X.X.X:7687";
                String username = "neo4j";
                String password = "neo4j";
                driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(username, password));
                Session session = driver.session();
                Log.e("Client", "Connessione effettuata");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Client", "Connessione non effettuata");
            }`
```

How can I fix it?

I would like the neo4j server to connect

Comment: The setting names do not match the documented ones: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/. It should be `server.bolt.listen_address`.

Comment: @fbiville yes, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @fbiville when I try to connect from neo4j it says: " ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the Neo4j certificate is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3"

Comment: why does it work only with localhost and not my network?